# How to create multi table side by side with fpdf

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, fpdf

Can someone teach me how to create a table side by side like this with fpdf:
[image]

I'm trying to combine the multiple column with the creating table tutorial but failed. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you got struggled with fpdf, you can try to do it with [Debenu Quick PDF](http://www.debenu.com/products/development/debenu-pdf-library/trial/).
This C# code returns the exact result which is on your picture. It is done with merged cells, but also you can use zero border width - it depends on your needs. Of course you can change the width and the color of the borders.

```
DPL.LoadFromFile("blank.pdf", "");
DPL.SetOrigin(1); //the top left page corner will be used for the origin 
DPL.SetMeasurementUnits(0); //the units are approximately the same as a "point"

string content1, content2, content3;
content1 = "1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>20";
content2 = "21<br>22<br>23<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>30";
content3 = "31<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>40";

int tableID1 = DPL.CreateTable(20, 3); //20 rows, 3 columns
DPL.SetTableColumnWidth(tableID1, 1, 1, 20); //width of the first column
DPL.SetTableColumnWidth(tableID1, 2, 3, 40); //width of the second and third column
DPL.SetTableRowHeight(tableID1, 1, 20, 10); //height of all rows
DPL.MergeTableCells(tableID1, 2, 1, 20, 1); //merge the cells from second row to 20. row and from 1. column to 1. column - merge the cells of the first column
DPL.MergeTableCells(tableID1, 2, 2, 20, 2); //merge the cells of the second column
DPL.MergeTableCells(tableID1, 2, 3, 20, 3); //merge the cells of the third column
DPL.SetTableCellContent(tableID1, 2, 1, content1); //add the content
DPL.DrawTableRows(tableID1, 50, 50, 700, 1, 0); //draw the table to the page

int tableID2 = DPL.CreateTable(20, 3);  // second table
DPL.SetTableColumnWidth(tableID2, 1, 1, 20);
DPL.SetTableColumnWidth(tableID2, 2, 3, 40);
DPL.SetTableRowHeight(tableID2, 1, 20, 10);
DPL.MergeTableCells(tableID2, 2, 2, 20, 2);
DPL.MergeTableCells(tableID2, 2, 3, 20, 3);
DPL.MergeTableCells(tableID2, 2, 1, 20, 1);
DPL.SetTableCellContent(tableID2, 2, 1, content2); 
DPL.DrawTableRows(tableID2, 160, 50, 700, 1, 0);

int tableID3 = DPL.CreateTable(20, 3);   //third table
DPL.SetTableColumnWidth(tableID3, 1, 1, 20);
DPL.SetTableColumnWidth(tableID3, 2, 3, 40);
DPL.SetTableRowHeight(tableID3, 1, 20, 10);
DPL.MergeTableCells(tableID3, 2, 2, 20, 2);
DPL.MergeTableCells(tableID3, 2, 3, 20, 3);
DPL.MergeTableCells(tableID3, 2, 1, 20, 1);
DPL.SetTableCellContent(tableID3, 2, 1, content3); 
DPL.DrawTableRows(tableID3, 270, 50, 700, 1, 0);            

DPL.SaveToFile("tables.pdf");
```

You can find the description of the functions on this site:

http://www.debenu.com/docs/pdf_library_reference/CreateTable.php